# preg_match quantifier does not work PHP 5.5

Tags: php, regex, unicode

Hi i'm trying to use this pattern `/^(–*\s*2\.2\.|2\.2\.)/`  to match this strings, each line is a different string.
**EDIT** sorry about the poor data formating

```
<?php
 $final_texts=array();
 $pattern='/^(–*\s*2\.2\.|2\.2\.)/';//this is generated automatically elsewhere btw
 $texts = array(
 "– 2.2.04 R",
 "–– 2.2.04.10 C",
 "–– 2.2.04.1 CO",
 "–– 2.2.04.2 CO",
 "–– 2.2.04.3 CO",
 "–– 2.2.04.4 CO",
 "–– 2.2.04.5 CO",
 "–– 2.2.04.6 CO",
 "–– 2.2.04.7 CO",
 "–– 2.2.04.8 CO",
 "–– 2.2.04.9 CO",
 "foooooooooooo",
 "barrrrrrrrrr",
 "-- foobar",
 "- 1123",
 );
 foreach($texts as $key=>$text){    
    if(preg_match($pattern, $text)){
        $final_texts[]=$text;
    }
  }
 print_r($final_texts); ?>
```

This is what i'm using `preg_match($pattern, $string)`
As i Understand it * means 0 or more of the former, but i'm no expert .

But only matches the first string and not the ones with more than one dash "–" keep in mind that they are different string inside an array and i iterate over it to do something. should i be doing something different in the pattern, i'm trying to match all strings that start with any amount of dashes and spaces follwed by the **2.2.** string. And I will have this problem with other numbers, and i may have strings with more than 2 dashes in the future so i don't see how can i solve this not using regex
i've allready test it here http://preg_match.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and have the same problem.
[demo](https://eval.in/177489) thanks to @hwnd for showing me this!

Comment: Do not use the `^` at the beginning, and use `preg_match_all`.

Comment: Thanks but shouldn't that indicate that i'm looking the pattern at the beggining of the string??

Comment: yes, but from what I understand; the entire block above is a single string.

Comment: @FabriR: To be clear: `^` means 'start of the string' by default, but if you use the m modifier, `^` means 'start of the line'

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear enough they are different strings, each line is a diffrent string.

Comment: @FabriR: You're using a different dash in your string. Change the expression to `/^([‒ – — ―]*\s*2\.2\.|2\.2\.)/` and it [should work](https://eval.in/177469).

Comment: @AmalMurali thanks this worked. weird thing though i really checked that they were all the same character.

Comment: @AmalMurali i rechecked what i've said and in the place where the strings are generated is like this  `str_repeat("–", $level)` $level indicates the depth of the category(i'm trying to sort them) and is really confusing why it matches when there is one dash but not when there are more. Anyway what you showed me worked and you should take all the credit.if you post this i will accept your answer. cannot upvote yet too newbie.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the cause of this is the unicode dash you have placed in your regular expression. I recommend using the [Unicode property `\p{Pd}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) ( *any kind of hyphen or dash* ) to match these characters.

```
/^(\p{Pd}+\s*2\.2\.|2\.2\.)/mu
```

**Note:** The `m` (multi-line) modifier causes `^` to match the beginning of each line. The `u` modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE and Pattern strings are treated as (UTF-8).

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/177501)

Just for thought, instead of iterating over your array use [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) here.

```
$final_texts = preg_grep('/^(\p{Pd}+\s*2\.2\.|2\.2\.)/mu', $texts);
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/177506)

Comment: Nice choice of character class.

Comment: I see people are having a problem understanding my data i will fix that. It is not a single string each line is a string. https://eval.in/177477 you can see these here

Comment: There i edited the post again, sorry for the poor formating at the beggining!

Answer (score 0):

En dash is encoded as three bytes (`E2 80 93`) in UTF-8. A quantifier will only be applied to the last byte so `–*` is equivalent to `\x{e2}\x{80}\x{93}*`.

You can simply wrap the Unicode character in parentheses `(–)*` to apply the quantifier to all three bytes. Or if you don’t want to capture it, use non-capturing group `(?:–)*`.

Character sets will also work with Unicode characters `[–]`.

See [runnable](http://runnable.com/VLnpPGQF0Osl38TY/unicode-character-matching-with-quantifier-for-php).